How can I get cloud thickness data or cloud base height and cloud top height?
I'm a lil bit lost in how can I find the cloud height/thickness.
Like I have cloud water content in g/m2 only but I need it in g/m3 and that's can be done if we know the cloud thickness.
If the cloud thickness is not available, we can calculate it using the cloud base height and the cloud top height.
Where can I find these heights?
Thank you.

To compute cloud thickness you need cloud cover on pressure/vertical levels.  This is something computed by the model cloud cover scheme, you cannot make it up... Some models already provide cloud top and base in the output
